# Cannot resolve postgresql issue with UNION ALL

Tags: postgresql

I am working in postgresql 9.2.15 and I am trying to create a SUBTOTAL ROW in my output.  I am encountering this error in my UNION ALL and I tried fixing it with a conversion to TEXT in the column where I've applied a COUNT but I am still getting the same error.
**Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thank you.**

Here is my error:

```
ERROR:  UNION types numeric and text cannot be matched
LINE 117: SELECT II.school_id || ' Subtotal', null, null, null, null, ...
                 ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: UNION types numeric and text cannot be matched
SQL state: 42804
Character: 4725
```

Here is my query code:

```
SELECT II.school_id, II.syear, II.student_id, II.last_name, 
     II.first_name,
     II.AddressSchool, II.EnrolledSchool, II.Income_SchoolYear, 
     II.NumberInHousehold, 
     II.HouseholdMember, II.PayType, II.Income, II.AddedOn, II.AddedBy,
     II.CompletedEarlyChildhoodDocumentation, II.ApprovedByPrincipal, 
     II.ApprovedByEarlyChildhood,
     QI.QualifyingInfo_SchoolYear, QI.MethodOfQualifying, QI.Notes, 
     QI.ApprovedBy, QI.ApprovedDate
FROM II
INNER JOIN QI
ON II.student_id = QI.student_id
WHERE II.ApprovedByPrincipal IS NULL
AND II.ApprovedByEarlyChildhood IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT II.school_id || ' Subtotal', null, null, null, null,  
    null, null, null, null, 
    null, null, null, null, null,
    null, count(II.ApprovedByPrincipal)::text, null,
    null, null, null, null, null
FROM II
INNER JOIN QI
ON II.student_id = QI.student_id
WHERE II.ApprovedByPrincipal IS NOT NULL
AND II.ApprovedByEarlyChildhood IS NULL
GROUP by 1
ORDER BY II.school_id, II.student_id, II.last_name asc, II.first_name
```

Comment: `II.school_id` (1st part) is probably a number, but `II.school_id || ' Subtotal'` (2nd part) is definitely a string. And the `^` in the error message tells you precisely where the error is

Comment: What is Postgres 4.5?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I tried adding to the 2nd SELECT this SELECT CAST(II.school_id as varchar(20)) || ' Subtotal',
But still getting the same error?
school_id is defined as a numeric data type.

Comment: Also, sorry about my misprint on the Postgres version.  I typed out the wrong value.  I am working on PostgreSQL 9.2.15.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to cast the column in the **first** part to a varchar.

Comment: Thanks you for the help.  It's appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I have gotten around this by setting the null to int4 manually. So for example,

```
select 
first name,
last name,
address,
quantity
from table1
union all
first name,
last name,
null::int4 as quantity
from table2
```